# Select records from after last 6 AM

Tags: sql, t-sql

Have table: item (int) and timestamp (datetime).
Need to know if there are any records with timestamp after **last** 6 AM.

Example:

> At 5 AM it should check if there are any records from after 6 AM
>   yesterday.
>  AT 7 AM it should check if there are any records from
>   after 6 AM today

This could be done of course by making a variable with datepart as:

> if time now is < 6 AM datepart should be yesterday
>  if time now
>   is >= 6 AM datepart should be today

but there must be a simpler way ?

Comment: No, there's not a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

This expression should always return the most recent 06:00 in the past:

```
select DATEADD(hour,
     (DATEDIFF(hour,'2014-01-01T06:00:00',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)/24)*24,
                  '2014-01-01T06:00:00')
```

It works by asking how many hours have happened since some arbitrary, known, 6AM. We then round this number *down* to the closest multiple of 24 (by dividing and multiplying with integer maths), and add this number back onto the same, arbitrary, 6AM